# How to get values out of an object Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get values out of an object in firebase. I am able to print the object to the console ok :

```
 const profile = af.database.object('profile/1');

 profile.subscribe(console.log);
```

This prints out to my console the object of profile /1.  How do I access a specific value of that object and assign such as name ?

Comment: `profile.subscribe(console.log);` looks pretty weird to me. Do you mean something else? Maybe `console.log(profile)`?

Comment: Yeah it's angularfire , that why I am using subscribe,

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are getting a standard javascript object, you can access its value by doing this:

```
objectName.propertyName
```

Say you have an object set up like this:

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.name = "Object";
```

Then if you do

```
console.log(obj.name);
```

You will get the following in your console.

```
"Object"
```

See more here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: As it is Angular2 and Typescript wont let me access values using pure javascript , it just says its undefined. Thanks though  :)

Comment: Sorry. I thought it was just pure javascript. Have you tried `obj["name"]`? After some googling that's what I found some people are doing.